# What's the problem with my regular sentences?

Tags: python, regex

```py
import re

demo_str = "descr:          Copper Concentrate Mine"
re.findall(r"(.*?):\s+(.*?)", a, re.I)
```

output: [('descr', '')]

This result is not what I expected.
What I want is “[('descr', 'Copper Concentrate Mine')]”

Answer (score 3):

Remove the last `?` from the capturing group to make it greedy ([doc](https://regex101.com/r/SPpQ6q/1)):

```
import re

demo_str = "descr:          Copper Concentrate Mine"
print( re.findall(r"(.*?):\s+(.*)", demo_str, re.I) )
```

Prints:

```
[('descr', 'Copper Concentrate Mine')]
```

Answer (score 1):

This expression might also work:

```
import re

regex = r"([^:]+):\s*(.+)"
test_str = "descr:          Copper Concentrate Mine"
print(re.findall(regex, test_str))
```

#### Output

```
[('descr', 'Copper Concentrate Mine')]
```

---

> If you wish to explore/simplify/modify the expression, it's been
>   explained on the top right panel of
>   [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/PNEdp4/1/). If you'd like, you
>   can also watch in [this
>   link](https://regex101.com/r/PNEdp4/1/debugger), how it would match
>   against some sample inputs.

---

Answer (score 0):

The reason the second entry is empty is due to the non greedy dot `.*?` in the second part. It will match as least as possible.

As it is the last part in the expression and there are no boundaries or anchors following, an empty match will satisfy the condition.

Another option for your example data is to use [re.split](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split) on matching `:` surrounded by 0+ whitespace chars.

```
\s*:\s*
```

Or to match only a colon and 1+ whitespace chars:

```
:\s+
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jAsxHJ/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/PATdMG)

```
import re

demo_str = "descr:          Copper Concentrate Mine"
print(re.split(r"\s*:\s*", demo_str))
```

Result

```
['descr', 'Copper Concentrate Mine']
```